# Bootstrap CSS menu won't open when collapsed

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using Pico CMS. Here is the navigation code

```
<!-- Navigation -->
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-custom navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
        <div class="navbar-header page-scroll">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseID">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                Menu <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
            </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Broadstone Services</a>
        </div>

        <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
        <div class="navbar-collapse collapse" id="collapseID">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <li>
                    <a href="/">Home</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="about">About</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="solutions">Solutions</a>
                    </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="contact">Contact</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="blog">Blog</a>
                </li>

    </ul>
        </div>
        <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
    </div>
    <!-- /.container -->
</nav>
```

When my page is full screen, the menu items look great. However, when the page window is made a lot smaller (or on mobile) the menu doesn't expand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not loading the jQuery and Bootstrap JavaScript libraries that perform the functional uncollapse.

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

See http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/

For functional reference see: https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/master/dist/js/bootstrap.js#L557

Comment: Updated code references for the sources. I put them there as an example, preferably you should include them as local assets within your website's domain.

Comment: Effectively it's causing `Failed to find a valid digest in the 'integrity' attribute for resource 'http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js' with computed SHA-256 integrity 'KXn5puMvxCw+dAYznun+drMdG1IFl3agK0p/pqT9KAo='. The resource has been blocked.` so you can exclude the `integrity` check

Comment: How do I include these locally?

Comment: If they haven't been  already, upload them to your web server (like your current `/themes/clean-blog/css/bootstrap.min.css`). EG: use the following to replace the `src=""` attributes `http://broadstoneservices.com/themes/clean-blog/js/jquery.min.js` and `http://broadstoneservices.com/themes/clean-blog/js/bootstrap.min.js` and either put them in your `<head>` element or just above your `</body>` element.